# How JSON serialize Chromadb

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, langchain, chromadb

I had been working on a small test project in Azureml notebook environment. I had been using a relatively small chromadb to perform some vector search. Now I need to perform this task in a Azure pipeline and would like to upload this chromadb into Azure Blob Storage. It seems like I cannot upload the the chromadb directly into blob, and hence I looking for an alternative.
Anyone know how this can be achieved.
I had been also trying to use Azure Cognitive Search, and I am running into other numerous issues with Python SDK.

```
import json
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=chroma_db_path,
                   embedding_function=embeddings)
db_data = vectordb.to_json()
json_string = json.dumps(db_data)

Error: AttributeError: 'Chroma' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it myself (i.e. saving database to blob) but when I persisted the database using `persist()`, Chroma created a SQLite database by the name `chroma.sqlite` in the directory specified in `chroma_db_path`.

If your objective is to persist the entire database, one possible solution would be to upload this file as is in blob storage.